# Is it possible to use CPLEX in Android application?

Tags: android, cplex

I just want to know if there is any libraries that I can use, or maybe include some .jar files. I don't know how to do it or even start ,any help or clarification whether it is possible in the first place or not ? 
I already saw [this forum](https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00005TMk6I/ilog-cplex-for-android-application-?language=fr),but nobody did answer so I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/detailed-system-requirements-ibm-ilog-cplex-optimization-studio

you may find all available ports for CPLEX

For ports that are not there, you may call CPLEX in the cloud :

CPLEX is available in the cloud in docplexcloud and wml

https://developer.ibm.com/docloud/

https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/announcements/decision-optimization-now-available-in-watson-machine-learning-service

Answer (score 1):

You can use python on android and run CPLEX from the IBM cloud

in your app install : docplex and docloud (as python modules).

http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/getting_started_python.html

you do the tests with the trial version : https://developer.ibm.com/docloud/try-docloud-free/